# C# on Program start up, the 2nd form is already running?

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

Hi i got a program that have two forms..

it goes like this

> Form1(my main form)
>
> From2

Form2 will only show if it is called by form1,
basically when i start the program form1 is the only one there.
but whats weird is.. the timer inside Form2 is already running.

Anyone got an idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE:**

here the code i used

```
public partial class MainForm : Form, IMessageFilter 
{
    public Form2 f2 = new Form2();
 
}

public void ShowForm2()
{
f2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code? It's a little hard to tell what's going on from your description. Where are you declaring Form2? Where are you instantiating it? Where are you Show()ing it?

Comment: i declare it like this, public Form2 f2 = new Form2 ();    its inside public partial class MainForm.  Form2 only opens when my Form1 received a message from a server, then i call a method.. inside the method is f2.Show();

Comment: i dont know if this is the reason or what.. but is it possible that if i, already made the timer on form2 enabled = true on design view..  it will run even if i haven't called on form2? this is really confusing =(

Comment: How about placing the instantiation of Form2 to where the f2.Show() is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you said:

```
public Form2 f2 = new Form2 ();  // its inside public partial class MainForm
```

Is it like this:

```
public class MainForm {
     public Form2 f2 = new Form2();

     public void ShowForm2() {
         f2.Show();
     }
}
```

You should not do that, else you should create an instance of Form2 when needed, like this:

```
public class MainForm {
     public void ShowForm2() {
         Form2 f2 = new Form2();
         f2.Show();
     }
}
```

Now you are sure that the instance will exist only when the message is received and will avoid to running the timer in Form2 if it is hidden.

Comment: Thanks for that, I already updated my answer with your actual method `ShowForm2()`, good luck with it.

Comment: Hi This solves the problem, Even if made another error to my project, but its ok... well just to share.. i declare it that way. because im having problem also on closing down the Form2, since if i do it that way. it intermediately forget it,(a threading thing).. well thanks peyton

Comment: You can post another question for that, i am sure these guys don't mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

So based on your clarification, you're instantiating `Form2` when `Form1` is created... and so I'm guessing that the `Timer` is enabled by default and is instantiated when `Form2` is instantiated, so it starts right away.

You need to change it so that the timer isn't enabled until you show `Form2` (maybe in the `Load` event) or some other point later.

More code might be helpful though - I still feel like I'm stabbing the dark here.